# Regular Expression Scope Too Large

Tags: regex, floating-point, integer

I have created a (mostly) working regular expression that accepts any number > 0 or <= 12, allowing up to two decimal places. The problem is that it also accepts numbers between 12-13 such as 12.25, and also 0.

My regular expression pattern is `/^\b(0*([0-9]|1[0-2]))\b\.?[0-9]{0,2}$/`

How can I change this to prevent 0 or numbers greater than 12 from being accepted?

Comment: You have to special-case for `12`, then you could change `[0-2] `to `[0-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])0*(?:(?:\d|1[01])?(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?|12(?:\.0{0,2})?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WBwDeA/4) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3D%5B%5E1-9%5D*%5B1-9%5D)0*(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5Cd%7C1%5B01%5D)%3F(%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C2%7D)%3F%7C12(%3F%3A%5C.0%7B0%2C2%7D)%3F)%24):

[image]

If a digit after a decimal separator symbol is *required*, replace `{0,2}` with `{1,2}`:

```
^(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])0*(?:(?:\d|1[01])?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|12(?:\.0{1,2})?)$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])` - a positive lookahead that requires one non-zero digit (a digit from `1` to `9`) after any chars other than digits from `1` to `9`
- `0*` - any 0+ leading zeros
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?:\d|1[01])?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?` - `0` to `11` numbers (matched optionally, see the `?` after the first closing parenthesis) followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1 to 2 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `12(?:\.0{1,2})?` - `12` optionally followed with `.` and 1 to 2 digits
- `)` - end of a non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Mostly works, though it's still accepting 0. How do I also reject 0?

Comment: @JoeCoyle Sorry, I completely missed that part. Replace the first `[0-9]` with `[1-9]`. I updated all demos and explanations.

Comment: Thanks, getting close! I probably should have stated it more clearly in the question, but I also wanted to include numbers between 0-1, such as 0.25. Ideally, we could account for formatting like .25 as well, but that's optional.

Comment: Then you need `^(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])0*(?:(?:\d|1[01])?(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?|12(?:\.0{0,2})?)$`, see https://regex101.com/r/WBwDeA/4

Comment: Excellent--works perfectly. Can't thank you enough!